# How to read Header information in Angular2 when the app is loaded first time?

Tags: angular, http-headers

Is it possible to read the header information in the Angular 2 app when it is loaded first time (or event javascript how we do it)

We have an angular2 app which starts when a user is redirected to it from another app. The other app will not only redirect but will also add some headers which our app will need to read and use. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of redirect is it?

Comment: authentication successful redirect. When a user is authenticated successfully on that application and when user clicks a link in that app, user is redirected to our app with some headers. Does it need to be some specific redirect of some sort?